# Creating a nested custom resource in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an professional model and a citizen model. What i am trying to do is a nested citizen registration inside the professional model, but i am stumbling a lot...

i was using in my routes:

```
  get "professional/citizen_edit/:id" => "professional#citizen_edit", as: :professional_citizen_edit
  get "professional/cidadao_show/:id" => "professional#citizen_show", as: :professional_citizen_show
  put "profissionais/cidadao_update/:id" => "professional#citizen_update", as: :professional_citizen_update
```

And using custom controller actions everywere
And was almost done, but i had got stuck when trying to add a button for a new citizen
(my form page was stuck in the update action and i cant get it to work with both actions)

While trying to solve this issue, i found this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
and this:

```
  namespace :professionals do
    resources :registrations
  end
```

Looked a more elegant way to deal with my problem. But now i dont know what to do with the controller! I got these routes:

```
professionals_registrations GET    /professionals/registrations(.:format)                           professionals/registrations#index
POST   /professionals/registrations(.:format)                           professionals/registrations#create
new_professionals_cadastro GET    /professionals/registrations/new(.:format)                       professionals/registrations#new
edit_professionals_cadastro GET    /professionals/registrations/:id/edit(.:format)                  professionals/registrations#edit
professionals_cadastro GET    /professionals/registrations/:id(.:format)                       professionals/registrations#show
PUT    /professionals/registrations/:id(.:format)                       professionals/registrations#update
DELETE /professionals/registrations/:id(.:format)                       professionals/registrations#destroy
```

And i tried to add a custom controler "registrations" either inside app/controllers or app/controllers/professionals but i cant find the controler right path and keep getting

```
at: http://127.0.0.1:3000/Profissionais/registrations)
uninitialized constant Profissionais::RegistrationsController
```

Anyone have any clue of what to do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using namespaces you have to do two things:

- Move all controllers to a folder under `app/controllers/` with the same name as your namespace
- Let your controllers inherit from a controller with the same name of your namespace (in your case `Profissionais`)

The reason why you are getting that error is that the parent controller `Profissionais` does not exist (i.e. uninitialized constant)

As the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing) states, all your controllers must be under a namespace (in your case `Profissionais::`) as you defined it in `routes.rb`.

**HINT:**

I haven't tried it myself but it may also be possible to use modules to create your namespace instead of inheriting from a parent controller residing in `app/controllers/`. For more see [here](http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1-ruby-primer/chapters/35-modules/lessons/80-modules-as-namespaces)

Comment: I also named the registrations controller just registrations.rb instead registrations_controller.rb
But still getting Expected [long PATH]app/controllers/profissionais/registration_controller.rb to define Profissionais::RegistrationController. How the inherit should look like in class definition?

Comment: I think it is: "class Profissionais::RegistrationController < ApplicationController"
But now i get:
NameError at /profissionais/registrations
uninitialized constant Registration

Comment: You have to inherit from `profissionais` which in turn inherits from application controller. Note that you have to create class `profissionais` in order to be able to inherit from it.

Comment: Nevermind. Wrong stuff write on the controller. Fixed!